# How to maintain image size when converting canvas to blob

Tags: javascript, image-processing, html5-canvas, blob, jpeg

When I do the following:

```
canvas.toBlob(blob=>{

}, 'image/jpeg', 1);
```

Somehow the blob is downgraded to 300px*150px. How can I maintain the original size of the canvas image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

By default, the width and height  of canvas are 300px and 150px respectively.

I need to do the following:

```
<canvas width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Setting the dimensions with CSS won't do.